# Is there a way to implement a free trial followed by a one-time-purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I am using App Store Connect, Swift and Xcode. I want to offer my app for free in the AppStore, then the customers can "buy" a free trial and after the free trial expired they can buy the app, if they don't they shouldn't be able to use the app. I know there is a free trial option for AR subscriptions but is there something like a free trial and one-time-purchase?

Answer (score 1):

If you have users , then you have a login system , so from the moment the user uses the features or any kind of action , store an attribute in his model in server with the start date , after that you can control to show/hide the content and to present the payment of the non-consumable IAP accordingly

Comment: Thanks, that already helped lot. Where and how do I store the start date?

Comment: this is relevant to the back end developer to store the current data with timeZone of country at the time you send a request to the server to start setting the start date

Comment: Then you can monitor the users startDate against the expiration of their free trial and if they are outside that date range you can direct them to a view prompting them to the non-consumable IAP. Not sure what your app is or your experience with the backend, but Firebase has a suite of tools and documentation you can use to set this up.